# class library to include and test gui

Tags: c#

I want to start out saying this is part of a homework assignment, but I'm not asking for any code. I have to create a abstract base class, with 2 subclasses, including a virtual method, and a interface. I have made all my classes and the interface, but I am stuck in creating a class to test the GUI. I have referenced all the class libraries with subclasses and the interface, but my book has another class called PresentationGUI.cs in the example. I have created the class before the form, but do not know how to implement this class to "work" with the form, I have set the presentation class as a startup project, but cannot figure out how to make it communicate with the Windows Form Designer code. In the book the presentation class, has Windows Forms code generated along with references to the namespaces of the different classes, within this presentation class, along with parts of the subclasses, but I am lost at how to accomplish this. The code in the book looks like this (I shortened it to save time):

```
01  using System;                //// I get an error if I type this in
02  using System.Drawing;
03  using System.Collections.Generic;
04  using System.ComponentModel; 
05  using System.Windows.Forms;
06  using System.Data;
07  using ClubNamespace;       //// to reference the subclasses
08  using IntermuralNamespace;
09   
10  namespace PresentationGUI 
11  {
12  public class PresentationGUI : System.Windows.Forms.Form
13  {
14  private Club aClub;
15  private Intermural aIntermural;
16  private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupbox1;
17  private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
18  //// and other Windows.Forms object oriented buttons and so-forth
19   
20  public PresentationGUI ()
21  {
22  Initialize Component ();
23  }
24  /// #Windows Designer Code to add controls
25  static void Main()
26  {
27  Application.Run(new PresentationGUI());
28  }
29  private void Presentation_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
30  {
31  aClub = new Club ("ACM", "Jones", "Davis 203", "Tuesday");
32  aIntermural = new Intermural ("Winners", "Joe Smith", "Gym 3", "VolleyBall")
33  }
```

My instructor said that by creating the PresentationGUI class and setting it as startup, before adding controls to the form will create the private Systems.Windows.Forms.Label label1; to the class itself, but that doesn't happen when I create my class. I have even added my subclasses as references to the PresentationGUI class after I made it a startup project, even the interface, I omitted it in my code above (I used my exact code from the book which is not using a interface). Does this have to do with adding the using System part at the top, or do I have to add the private Windows.Forms part myself to reference the controls? Or is there a different way that I need to create the PresentationGUI class library? How can I make a class with a Initialize Component() and Main() method? Do I somehow need to reference this with the Form Design, or is it part of the Form Design, if it is how can I make it part of the Form design? Sorry for all the questions and I know the answer is probably simple, but there is extremely little about this in my book and online, and I can't figure out what I need to do to implement this. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Start by removing line numbers

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow, this is quite a large question, usually they need to be broken up but I think I know how the book is confusing you and I trust you'll read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/FAQ) before posting again.

**"How can I make a class with a Initialize Component() and Main() method? Do I somehow need to reference this with the Form Design, or is it part of the Form Design, if it is how can I make it part of the Form design?"**

Forms are classes too, they just derive from System.Windows.Form. Sounds like you are just creating normal classes (right click on project and select Add New Item > Windows Form not a normal class)

Create new Project > Winforms > rename the Form1 to PresentationGUI, while viewing the form designer, expand the ToolBox of controls, drag a GroupBox control onto the form and Label control as well.

Right click the PresentationGUI Form > View Code. You will see it has this method in the class constructor::

```
InitializeComponent();
```

Right click this method name and select Goto Definition (or F12) and this is where you'll see the Form Designer code - that was generated by you dragging controls onto the form surface.

Right click the program.cs file > View Code > it will have:

```
static void Main()
{
Application.Run(new PresentationGUI());
}
```

That book you have is putting all this knowledge together (not using a partial class for the designer generated code).

Finally in your PresentationGUI forms code, put in the Form_Load event:

```
private void PresentationGUI_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
aClub = new Club ("ACM", "Jones", "Davis 203", "Tuesday");
aIntermural = new Intermural ("Winners", "Joe Smith", "Gym 3", "VolleyBall")
}
```

*I prefer to add events to forms and controls using the Properties window, eg: Open PresentationGUI n design view, press F4, in the properties window you'll see a lightning bolt button, this shows all the events you can add to the Form or Control you have selected.*

Regarding hooking up controls to the class, with 2 subclasses, including a virtual method, and a interface, you use Binding. Eg a ListBox1.DataSource = BusObjectTier.aClub;

Regarding the main title of the question `I am stuck in creating a class to test the GUI`.

**Use Binding so that you dont need to write tests for the GUI. You test your business logic that controls are bound to.**

Comment: Thank You Thank You Thank You, I've bee trying to figure that out for about a week. No matter where I looked I could not find anything on the subject. You were so much help!!!

Comment: No worries Eric, for extra points (and instantly becoming a better programmer) try doing unit tests on `ClubNamespace` using a mocking framework, NSubstitute I find is one of the easiest frameworks. Here is a good article on the topic (you an adjust its meaning with Webconfig into anything): http://www.blog.ingenuitynow.net/How+To+Unit+Test+Code+That+Uses+AppSettings+From+WebConfig.aspx and also this one for integration tests: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slange/archive/2009/09/03/data-driven-tests-in-team-system-using-excel-as-the-data-source.aspx