# How to organize a vb.net code?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I Don't want to write all my code in one class,can i write a sub elsewhere and call it from my main class?

for example i have this code calling a navigateRecord Sub that i wrote at the end of my main class:

```
Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    If inc <> maxrows - 1 Then
        inc = inc + 1
        NavigateRecords()
    Else
        MsgBox("No More Rows")
    End If


End Sub
```

And at the end of the class i wrote the sub:

```
Private Sub NavigateRecords()

    txtStdId.Text = ds.Tables("db1").Rows(inc).Item(0)
    txtStdName.Text = ds.Tables("db1").Rows(inc).Item(1)
    txtStdLname.Text = ds.Tables("db1").Rows(inc).Item(2)
    txtStdAdress.Text = ds.Tables("db1").Rows(inc).Item(3)


End Sub
```

can i write the navigate record sub in a other place and call it from the main class? and thankyou

Comment: Of course you can, but... *why* do want to relocate `NavigateRecords` to a different "place"? What makes you think or suspect that your current approach is not good enough?

Comment: That being asked, may I humbly recommend that you read a tutorial on the VB.NET language, and/or about OO programming in general. It appears that you are lacking a basic understanding of class types and how to instantiate and use them.

Comment: I want to minimize the code in my class so i want to write navigate records elsewhere can you tell me how please?

Comment: Stakx's advice to read up on OOP fundamentals is sound advice, Elie.  You really do need to start there as a more detailed explanation won't make sense to you otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Look up [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Making code reusable, encapsulated, polymorphic and simple using inheritance, and abstraction are the tenants of good computer programming.

A good example is the VB function called [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). You pass it a from and to date and the interval (hours, days, months, years) you wish to return.

Imagine if you had to write code to determine the difference between dates in all parts of your code, it would be *procedural programming*. We all hate that. Its better to make one function you can call "abstractly" from various coding implementations and purposes and re-use in an encapsulated fashion. Its one of the keys to becoming a good programmer.

If you had a class called PeopleRecord with 4 fields:

```
Public Class PeopleRecord
Public Id as string 'Better to use an Integer
Public StdName as string
Public StdLname as string
Public StdAdress as string
End Class
```

Then in your winform you use a BindingSource control to bind to the PeopleRecord Class.

In Design Time set each TextBox control to bind to a field in the BindingSource. Then do all your navigation logic in the PeopleRecord class.

The big benefit is when it comes to separation of concerns and being able to unit test your logic, which is hard to do if all the logic is embedded in the presentation tier (not [in a control free Business Logic Library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560277/class-library-to-include-and-test-gui)).